# Does silence remove freeze effects?

Tags: hearthstone

If one of my minions is frozen (for example with a [blizzard](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/276-blizzard)) can I silence it to remove the freeze effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does.

From [Gamepedia](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Silence_(ability)):

> It is possible to silence your own minions, which can be useful for removing Freeze effects and negative enchantments